# Can I create a table in excel with xlwings with python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am working in a report in excel and python, the main sheet contain a table. But every time I update the report the table format disappear and the table is converted to  range.
here is my code

```
excel_app = xw.App(visible=False)  
wb = excel_app.books.open(path_open)  
ws = wb.sheets('Full_table')    
ws.cells(1, 1).options(index=False, header=True).value = my_data
```

Would be possible to update the report keeping the table instead of having a range all the time?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your data is in a dataframe called my_Data_table

following code can help achieve your goal

```
import xlwings as xw
book = xw.Book()
ws = book.sheets.active
ws.range("A1").options(index=False).value = my_Data_table
```

## paste your data to excel

```
tbl_range = ws.range("A1").expand('table')
```

## create table in excel

```
ws.api.ListObjects.Add(1, ws.api.Range(tbl_range.address))
```

Comment: What happened ?? @RuddiRodriguez

Comment: as of xlwings 0.21 (released Nov 9, 2020), there is native support for tables in xlwings. See https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Tables.add

Comment: the url for xlwings docs changed, here is the current link: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api/tables.html#xlwings.main.Tables.add